# Proving Convergence or Divergence using Comparison test

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm asked to prove the convergence or divergence of the below series using the comparison test.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[3]{(n-1)}-\sqrt[3]{n}$$

I've reduced the above series to $\sqrt[3]{n}(\sqrt[3]{(1-\frac{1}{n}})-1)=U_n$, but after taking $V_n$ as $\sqrt[3]{n}$ and applying the limit, $\lim_{n\to {\infty}}\frac{U_n}{V_n}$ yields me zero, but the value has to be greater than zero for the comparison test to work. So I'm in a dilemma, am I doing something wrong?

Feel free to correct me  if I'm wrong in my calculations.

Comment: What's the meaning of the first and the second $=$ signs from your question?

Comment: I've assigned the series to $U_n$

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I want to know the meaning of the $=$ sign in $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}=\sqrt[3]{(n-1)}-\sqrt[3]{n},$$for instance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in a hurry I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

By binomial expansion prove that

$$\sqrt[3]{n}-\sqrt[3]{(n-1)}\ge \frac13 \frac1{n^{2/3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Firstly, remember that $x^{3} - y^{3} = (x-y)(x^{2} + xy +y^{2})$. Hence we get:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{n} - \sqrt[3]{n-1} & = \sqrt[3]{n} - \sqrt[3]{n-1}\times\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^{2}} + \sqrt[3]{n(n-1)} + \sqrt[3]{(n-1)^{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{n^{2}} + \sqrt[3]{n(n-1)} + \sqrt[3]{(n-1)^{2}}}\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^{2}} + \sqrt[3]{n(n-1)} + \sqrt[3]{(n-1)^{2}}} \geq \frac{1}{3\sqrt{n^{3}}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the question I posted.